# Camera calibration (intrinsics) parameters in ARCore

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

Is there any way of getting camera intrinsics parameters from ARCore, similar to what [ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2875730-intrinsics) provides? I've tried using [LENS_INTRINSIC_CALIBRATION](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/ImageMetadata.html#LENS_INTRINSIC_CALIBRATION) from ImageMetadata, but evidently this constant is not actually supported (I've tried using it on Pixel 2).

Comment: Same in my case. Camera calibration gave some unreliable parameters.

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do? Maybe it just has another name ...

Comment: @StevenMohr in any photogrammetry application, camera intrinsics are important. It contains focal length and information related to lens and image sensor

Comment: I'm using a custom computer vision library essentially doing a variation of SfM. That library needs camera intrinsics in a form of 2x3 matrix (focal lengths and principal point offset). I could derive approximate values from the projection matrix, but this is inconvenient and error-prone. Apple's ARKit provides exactly what I need.

Comment: @nbsrujan I understand how camera intrinsics are important for photogrammetry, but how would that translate into ARCore. maybe I should be asking DmitryA what he is looking to achieve...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand this is certainly not available in ARCore at this point, especially since focal length is locked. I suggest you report this as an issue on the ARCore github and have people write their support for the feature and hopefully it will get implemented!

Comment: Thanks, I noticed @nbsrujan has just created an issue for that.

Comment: Great. Would you mind linking to the issue here? If you feel like I helped out would much appreciate being marked as answer or some other boost. :)

Comment: Here is the link to the issue: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/112

Comment: Thanks! @DmitryA would you mind explaining a little bit of how this data will help you create ARCore apps? I'm just wondering the application that you're thinking about. For example, I understand why it is needed for photogrammetry, but that doesn't seem like an AR style experience...although I suppose maybe it can be made to be so?

Comment: A particular third-party library that I'm using does require camera calibration matrix for processing raw image data and building its own point clouds. Then the results are presented using ARCore.

Comment: @DmitryA interesting. I'd love to know what you're building!

Answer (score 2):

**It's possible.** But these parameters are only gettable (like in ARKit).

> ARCore's class [CameraIntrinsics](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/CameraIntrinsics) provides information about the physical characteristics of the device camera, for the camera image (CPU) or texture (GPU). The `CameraIntrinsics` is a long-lived object, and the properties of `CameraIntrinsics` may be updated every time `Session.update()` is called.

```
public class CameraIntrinsics
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Camera intrinsics were added to ARCore as of the [1.3 release](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/releases).

Answer (score 0):

For now you can use projection matrix to get `fx, fy, cx, cy`.
But distortion is impossible to obtain, although there is a chance images are already undistorted.

Answer (score 0):

Trying a few things inspired by the first step described [here](https://github.com/thestr4ng3r/arcore-patch), I was able to find the intrinsic parameters for the supported devices in the ARCore APKs. You need to get the [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) and run this in the same folder where you downloaded the ARCore APK (v1.2 in this example):

```
apktool -q d -s -r ARCore_1_2.apk -o ARCore_1_2
```

This will create a folder called ARCore_1_2, then go to `./lib/arm64-v8a` and unpack `libdevice_profile_loader.so` (with 7zip for instance) into a new folder for convenience. Then, open the file `.rodata` in the newly created folder with a text editor. Most of the file's content is formatted as an XML, just look for the name of the phone you're working with and you'll find the intrinsic parameters within the tag . There are also some IMU calibration data and extrinsics, but it's not clear how are they're used.

I haven't tested the parameters myself, but will do in the next few days...

Answer (score 0):

Actually  `LENS_INTRINSIC_CALIBRATION` is supported in pixel 2. You just need to confirm that your APK has access to the camera. You can manually give your app permission by going into settings.